# python returns an operand for logical operators but php returns 1

Tags: php, python, logical-operators

```
(45 or False)
```

Above statement returns 45 as the out put in python, rather than returning True or False or (0 or 1).

But in php It returns 1 as the output. what is the rationality behind this?

Comment: `or` returns the value that determines the outcome of the expression. That's just how it is defined. Are you asking why the language was designed this way?

Comment: but in php, It returns 1 as the out put.

Comment: any reason for minus marks?

Comment: @dulajsanjaya, in php it also gives 45: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b5d0e1b964f6bdcd3983ba47dc67b9eed60915c5

Comment: @FelixKling. Yes i want to know the rationality behind this?

Comment: @Dekel But if you add parenthesis like this $t = (45 or False);   ,It returns bool(true)

Comment: @Dekel: that's not quite right. `or` is weird because it has a different precedence. The code is executed as `($t = 42) or false`.

Comment: correct, in php the `or` operator gives you the result of the evaluation (true if one of the sides are not false, false otherwise).